# Simplify scientific number format and change formatting

Tags: php, numbers, notation

Is there a tricky way to print in a "round" way the scientific numbers such as:

```
2.9560343062229E-10
```

let be converted to 2.95^10. Also, how to split the exponent in order to print 2.95<sup>-10</sup> in HTML notation?

Comment: Use a regular expression to get the parts of the number. Then use `number_format` to print the mantissa with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Mind you, `2.95^-10` is something entirely different from `2.95e-10` in my book. It would confuse me as a reader in scientific texts (after all, 2e3 => 2000, 2^2 => 2*2*2 = 8).

Comment: you are absolutely right! my fault.. thanks for this fix, you made my day

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm done :P Thanks for your suggestions.
Quckest way:

```
$str = explode("E", $str);
return round($str[0],2)."<sup>".$str[1]."</sup>";
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple rounding to 2 in scientific notation:

```
$string = sprintf("%.2e",$number);
```

Custom format:

```
$exp = floor(log10($number));
$string = round($number/pow(10,$exp),2)."<sup>".$exp."</sup>";
```